# How to stop Javascript runtime error notifications in Visual Studio

Tags: debugging, javascript, visual-studio-2010

I used a plugin which tries to get value by many methods, because some of them are not implemented in all browsers. The code is working everywhere and performs fine.

The problem is that IE does not support a Javascript function that is called.  When the non-implemented browser function is called, I see the same window every time:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method"

I want to stop the error from showing in Visual Studio.  Is there any way to configure my Visual Studio to never break on errors and not tell me about them?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Go into your Internet Options in IE and under the Advanced tab you can select Disable Script Debugging for both IE and Other, should stop breaking on errors.

Comment: but i am already try by disable both [IE Debug and other Debug].

Comment: Did not work out for me. Visual studio still complaining about the same javascript error

Comment: This stopped me running in IE all together